Zero map on the $E^2$ page induces zero map?
This is probably a stupid question.
Let $F \rightarrow E \rightarrow B$ be a fibration and $G_*$ the generalized homology theory in the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence.
Let $F' \rightarrow E' \rightarrow B'$ be another fibration and suppose we have a morphism $\phi$ between the two (fibrations).
[That is, we have a map $\phi_1 : E \rightarrow E'$ and $\phi_2 : B \rightarrow B'$ such that the diagram commutes]
By the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence, we have
$H_p(B; G_q F) \cong E^{2}_{p,q} \Rightarrow G_{p+q}(E)$ and similarly for the second fibration.
So this gives a map $\phi_*$ from the $E^2$ page of the spectral sequence of the first fibration to the $E^2$ page of the spectral sequence of the second fibration.
Suppose this map is zero, for all terms except possibly at the $y$-axis (that is, for all terms  with $p = 0$). More precisely, suppose $\phi_*(E^{2}_{p,q}) = 0$ for all $p \geq 1$.
Does it mean that $G_{n}(E) \rightarrow G_{n}(E')$ is also zero (for all $n \geq 1$)?
Edit : Looking at the comments, it seems that it is false.
However, I am interested in the following special case :
$E = B = X$ (with the fibration given by the identity map)
$E' = B' = X'$ (with the fibration given by the identity map) [$X$ and $X'$ are different spaces]
[So $F = pt$, and $F' = pt$]
and $G_n = \Omega^{SO}_n$.

See my answer here.

I see. Thanks! Actually what I have in mind is the following case : $E = B = X, F = pt$ and $E' = B' = X', F' = pt$. (Of course, $X$ and $X'$ are different) The map $E \rightarrow B$ is the identity (also for the second fibration). Would it work in this particular case?

Oh and I forgot to add that I'm considering $G_n = \Omega_n^{SO}$.

@CoffeeTime Please add these things to the question itself.

Okay, I have added it to the question.
